# How do you handle attachments in your web application?

Tags: asp.net, file

Due to a lack of response to my original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124258/how-would-you-allow-users-to-edit-attachments-in-a-web-application), probably due to poor wording on my part.  Since then, I have thought about my original question and decided to reword it, hopefully for the better! :)

We create custom business software for our customers, and quite often they want attachments to be added to certain business entities.  For example, they want to attach a Word document to a customer, or an image to a job.  I'm curious as to how other are handling the following:

- How the user attaches documents? Single attachment? Batch attachment?
- How you display the attached
  documents? Simple list?  Detailed list?
- And the killer question, how the
  user then edits attached documents?  Is this even possible in a web environment?  Granted the user can just view the attachment.
- Is there a good control library to help manage this process?

Our current development environment is ASP.NET and C#, but I don't think this is a pretty agnostic question when it comes to development tools, save for the fact I need to work in a web environment.

It seems we always run into problems with the customer and working with attachments in a web environment so I  am looking for some **successes** that other programmers have had with their user base on how best to interact with attachments.

Comment: Can using stuff like a WYSIWYG editor for documents or some javascript/flash based image editing web-application be the solution for you? If yes, we can think of a way to integrate those in...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Start with one file upload control ("Browse button"), and use JavaScript to dynamically add more upload controls if they want to attach multiple files in a single batch.
- Display them in a simple list format (Filename, type, size, date), but provide full details somewhere else if they want them.
- If they want to edit the files, they have to download them, then re-upload them.  Hence, you need a way that they can say "this attachment overrides that old attachment".
- I'm not familiar with C# and ASP.NET, so I can't recommend any libraries that will help.

Comment: This is also how I have handled this in the past.

Comment: My big problem is that my users always complain about the re-uploading part.  There has got to be a better way.

Comment: Since the files reside on the server, there really isn't any way that they can edit them "in place" unless you want to set up some kind of network file sharing (like WebDAV).  As long as you have to go through the a vanilla CGI webserver, you have to send/receive a complete file to change it.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/